# Can HashSet store only one of two un-equal() added elements in multithreaded context? How?

Tags: java

Is it possible in multithreaded applications to have a situation when:

1. Two threads put different values in a `HashSet` (meaning not `equals()`)
2. Both `add()` invocations return `true`
3. But, despite all that, only *one* of the values actually ends up in the collection?

If it's possible (and it seems it *is*), what exact sequence of events leads to that?

Please note that I'm not asking how I can avoid it (I know about `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`). Rather, I'm curious how exactly it may happen. I thought I knew `HashMap`'s internals, but I'm a bit at a loss on this one

Java 17

Comment: I see two possibilities: internally HashSet maps the elements to the "buckets". In each bucket can be stored multiple elements that have a different hashCode. If you add two elements that are mapped to the same bucket they may overwrite each other (not checked the implementation if this is really possible). The second critical point comes when the HashSet resizes itself, thus increases the number of buckets and needs to reorder everything internally. At such a point a multi-threading data loss may be possible.

Comment: @Robert thanks for your input. That said, how can an element overwrite another even if they are mapped to the same bucket if the elements are eventually compared with `equals()`? Shouldn't the second element simply be linked to the first one (or more specifically, `HashMap.Node` that wraps the element)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily happen in a multithreading environment.

`HashSet` internally uses a `HashMap` and its `add()` method returns true if `HashMap.put()` returns `null`. From the source of [`HashSet.add()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java#L220):

```
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
```

And in `HashMap.put()` two threads can easily overwrite the entry that they store into the buckets.

[`HashMap.put()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L609):

```
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
    }
```

And [`HashMap.putVal()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L623):

```
    final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
                   boolean evict) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
        if ((tab = table) == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
            n = (tab = resize()).length;
        if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)    // (1)
            tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null); // (2)
        else {
            //...
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Two threads can execute the line (1) in parallel, deciding that the entry in the bucket is empty and store a new entry in (2) where one of the thread wins (i.e. its entry is stored).